# YCSB with mysql Duplicate entry for primary key

Tags: mysql, duplicates, ycsb

I try to run ycsb with mysql. Each time that I load and run one of the workloads of YCSB I delete manually the inserted records otherwise I get the message"DuPlicate entry'userx for key 'PRIMARY'". However when I load and run workload d although that I have already trupcate the table I'm facing duplicated primary key issues. Probably in this case when I run workload d it inserts data in the same filed as load does. If I create a table without a primery key I am not sure for the reliability of the ycsb test exeution. Is there a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem, my intuition is that YCSB manually writes the primary key of the table instead of using an auto-increment macro. So every time you run YCSB again, it starts from the first record therefore causing a duplicate primary key.

You need to config YCSB to run from the last inserted primary key. For example, if your load statement is 
`ycsb load jdbc -s -P workloads/workloada -P jdbc-binding/conf/db.properties -p recordcount=25000000 -s > load.dat`

(This loads db.properties as one of the parameters) 
You need to insert the line
`insertstart=100001` to your db.properties.
This number assumes that your ycsb ended at 100000 previously, so now the command will continue from 100001 onwards.